# Azure DevOps: make story visible on multiple sprintboards

Tags: azure-devops

As far as I can see it's only possible to share a user story to one sprintboard. Now I want to share a user story to a second sprintboard; for example because a second team needs to do activities for this story.
Is this possible in Azure DevOps? And if so how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

To share a work item to the boards of multiple teams, you can set up a common area path which is owned by all the teams. Then assign the work item to this area path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @ArnovanHemert, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer? Are the suggestions in my answer helpful for you?
As suggested, you can set up a common area path which is owned by all the teams so that work items assigned to this area path san be visible on the boards of multiple teams.